# Wildfly 9.0.2 Access is denied while setup server lock file

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-9

I am using `wildfly 9.0.2`, whenever I deploy my application, I am getting the following exception:

```
at org.jboss.as.messaging.jms.JMSService.doStart(JMSService.java:174)
        at org.jboss.as.messaging.jms.JMSService.access$000(JMSService.java:62)
        at org.jboss.as.messaging.jms.JMSService$1.run(JMSService.java:96)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
        at org.hornetq.core.server.NodeManager.setUpServerLockFile(NodeManager.java:185)
        at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager.start(FileLockNodeManager.java:66)
        at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl.start(HornetQServerImpl.java:429)
        at org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl.start(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:488)
        at org.jboss.as.messaging.jms.JMSService.doStart(JMSService.java:170)
        ... 8 more
```

I have checked the following points:

1. There is no other process using that file
2. If I delete `~\WildFly\standalone\data\messagingjournal\server.lock`, It again gets created even though no other process is running
3. If I restart my computer then it is working but after some time getting the same issue.

Does anyone know about it?

I have also attached the screenshot.[image: Screen shot of stacktrace]Thanks

Comment: When you delete the file do you have to delete it with an administrative user?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with admin too, but that also does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have delete this file / directory using unlocker and not this is fixed

Thanks

Comment: It seems like the user starting WildFly doesn't have write access to the directory then.

Comment: If this is the case then it should not allow to start the wildfly after restarting the system, Even it was working correctly before this issue